# Prevent an ASP.NET Menu from expanding over adjacent content

Tags: asp.net, css, blueprint-css

I have a two column layout, with a vertically oriented ASP.NET menu control in a narrow left column, and info related to the selected menu item in a wide right column:

```
<div class="span-4">
    <asp:Menu ID="categoryMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Vertical">
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
<div id="product-grid-pane" class="span-12 last">
    <asp:GridView ID="productGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" Width="100%">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

If a menu item contains long text, the menu simply expands over the grid.  How can I prevent this?  I might need two answers here: the pure CSS one, which would be very nice if the menu control rendered nice, simple UL elements, but it seems to prefer an impenetrable table based structure I may need additional help styling properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.net 4.0 the Menu control has a property named `RenderingMode` which you can set to `Table` or to `List`.

Otherwise perhaps you can give the Table `width:100%` and `table-layout:fixed` and your containing div `overflow:hidden`.